# runtime scheduling abstraction

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures

I am asked to write a program,an abstraction of runtime scheduling algorithms in C.The one I'm having problem with is "priority scheduling".It takes runtimes from the user like the other algorithms,except it also takes priorities of these processes.What troubles me is that I can't relate priorities with runtimes. How am I supposed to make a relationship between the priority and the runtime?According to algorithm,it runs the one with highest priority first.I just need to know how to make this connection,thanks.

Comment: "I can relate priorities with runtimes" -- please explain.  If there is a relationship, use it; if not, ignore the runtime.

Comment: Do you know anything about `struct`?

Comment: I recall struct,but don't exactly know the way it works,but if you can give an example of how it can be implemented on my code it would help me understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT :-**

Store the priorities in an array and sort out the array as per decreasing priorities and map  each priority with it's timing! Then,simply display the sorted array from starting and it's mapping with the process-time.

If the process are added at run-time, the you need to adopt greedy-algorithm to solve that problem. Select that process with highest priority in increasing order of incoming time.

### Check this to learn more [Interval Scheduling Algorithm](http://lonati.di.unimi.it/algo/0910/lab/kowalski6.pdf)

BTW,for implementing the real-scheduling algorithm :-

1. If the first process is currently running and then there comes a new process with the same or lesser priority level, then you should add just the new process to the FIFO data-structure(queue) so that it gets executed at the next(for equal/lesser priority).
2. If the first process is currently running, and a new process with a higher priority arrives and requests memory, you must pass the current process' upcoming instruction to the stack and execute the higher priority process and then return interrupt to execute the upcoming instruction!

I hope you are getting confused with the `DATA-STRUCTURES` to implement in a peculiar manner. Also,there is significant use of priority(higher)!

Comment: Thanks for your reply,but you misunderstand me,my fault sorry.There is no preemption and this is only an abstraction,there is no fifo or something,it's much more simple,i'm just a noob.It should take priority,and runtime,and match these.Like "process with runtime 32 sec has 4 priority,it should be executed right after the process with 21 sec and 5 priority and right before 18 with 3 priority."

Comment: Learnt `sorting of array`? Store the priorities in array and sort it and accordingly print the timings by establishing mapping from priorities to process-time!

Comment: @Morbidity-Check my answer now. I hope it helps. You need to implement Greedy Algorithm!